# Why am I getting an InvalidCastException when using COM interface?

Tags: c#, c++, com

I'm attempting to call a method from my C# program on an executable written in C++ that has a COM interface.

I've used an .old file which I ran through MIDL to get a .tlb which I ran through tlbimp to get my dll wrapper which I'm using in my C# project.

However when I run it I get "InvalidCastException: No such interface supported".

I have no idea what can be causing it. The only reference I've found to the issue is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa645736%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which states "If the cast fails, then an invalid cast exception is thrown" but nothing about why or what to do about it.

```
SparesClass spares = new SparesClass();
ISpares sparesInterface = (ISpares)spares;
sbyte result = sparesInterface.ReplaceLRU(m_iClassGobInt);
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Does the `SparesClass` implement `ISpares`?

Comment: It does yeah
```public class SparesClass : ISpares, Spares ```